# Computing quotients of abelian groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology

Suppose that $A \cong \oplus_{i = 1}^{n} Z_{p_{i}^{k_{i}}}$ is some finite abelian group, and $(a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n)$ generates a subgroup $N$. If $\langle (a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n) \rangle$ was a direct sum of subgroups in the decomposition, then the quotient $A / N$ would be easy to compute by everyone's favorite isomorphism theorem. But what about the case when it doesn't decompose nicely? Is it possible to redo the decomposition so that it does?

For instance, how would one "see at a glance" what $Z_8 \times Z_2 / \langle (2,1) \rangle$ is?

(These computations are coming up a lot in computing homology, hence the algebraic topology tag.)

Comment: Try the Smith normal form.

Comment: @lhf I know what the smith normal form is for a matrix with entries in a euclidean domain, but it's not really clear to me how to apply it here. Do you think you could post an answer with a simple example?

Comment: @lhf I think I see how to do it for computing homology groups of chain complexes, just not for some general finite Abelian groups and quotient.

Comment: @lhf Though I guess I could realize that group as the kernel of some map with smith normal form, and then surject onto the group I'm modding out by with some other mapped defined by a smith normal form from a free abelian group. I'll try to work out some examples. Thanks.

Comment: @lhf except that subgroups of free abelian groups are free, so that won't work. Sorry for the spam. I would appreciate an example or a reference though.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121255/factor-groups-and-isomorphisms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$Z_8 \times Z_2$ is the abelian group generated by $a$ and $b$ subject to $8a=0$, $2b=0$.

$(Z_8 \times Z_2) / \langle (2,1) \rangle$ is the abelian group generated by $a$ and $b$ subject to $8a=0$, $2b=0$, $2a+b=0$. From these equations, it is clear that $4a=0$ and $b=2a$. Hence $(Z_8 \times Z_2) / \langle (2,1) \rangle$ is the cyclic group of order $4$.

The [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) is the systematic way of doing these manipulations:

$$
\pmatrix { 8 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 } \space\to\space
\pmatrix { 0 & 8 \\ 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 } \space\to\space
\pmatrix { 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 8 } \space\to\space
\pmatrix { 1 & 2 \\ 0 & -4 \\ 0 & 8 } \space\to\space
\pmatrix { 1 & 0\\ 0 & -4 \\ 0 & 8 } \space\to\space
\pmatrix { 1 & 0\\ 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 }
$$